hyperref jumps wrong to the page just prior to the correct location
I have a tex file
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue
}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminary}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{theorem} \label{prelim}
Something here.
\end{theorem}

The jump to \cref{prelim} is wrong.

\end{document}


When I click on the cross-reference Theorem 1.1, it will jump to the previous page. Could you elaborate on this issue?

Update: I have found a fix from @Werner's comment:

You need a "counter stepping mechanism" in order to fix a position where the hyperlink will go. If this is not used, then you need to place a manual \phantomsection to mark the hyper target. So, place a \phantomsection before each \label where you want that \hyperref to jump to.

Is there a more systematic way (or "counter stepping mechanism" in @Werner's words) to solve this issue? Manually putting \phantomsection everywhere is not desirable for me...

it can happen, that the automatic anchor is separated from the theorem if the theorem is at the begin of a page as the hyperref patch is not perfect, see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/336. For a real solution more of amsthm must be changed. Write to the amsthm maintainer and ask them to add proper hyperref support.

@cfr unnumbered sections do have anchors and don't need a \phantomsection. Try it out.

I have reported this bug to tech-support@ams.org.

@cfr the intended effect of cross-reference is to jump right to the \label{...}. In my simple MWE, it jumps to the page prior to the correct location. So I strongly think this is a bug.

@cfr You can have a look at a previous comment by Ulrike Fischer.

ok, I see. well, if ulrike says so, so. you might want to investigate alternatives to amsthm in that case ....

@cfr It seems there is no perfect alternative...

no, but there may be something which has bugs more suited to your needs ;).

Here is a temporary hack that places the link target in the right spot. No promises it will continue to work if amsthm internals change :)
Right now, the link target is placed before the entire \@begintheorem command which does some complicated stuff before actually printing the theorem head and can cause the target to be misplaced.
This hack places the target right before the \thmhead command, which is part of \@begintheorem and actually prints the theorem head. I've done this with a combination of \AddToHookWithArguments and \AddToHookNext. For the former to work, the command needs to be defined with "LaTeX" commands (not \def) which is why I've redefined \@thm with \renewcommand. Here's the hack:
\NewCommandCopy\amsthm@thm\@thm
\renewcommand\@thm[3]{\amsthm@thm{#1}{#2}{#3}}% so hook with arguments works
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/@thm/before}{%
  \def\temp@num{#2}%
  \ifx\@empty\temp@num
  \else
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/thmhead/before}{\MakeLinkTarget{#2}}%
  \fi
  }

And the full example:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue
}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\amsthm@thm\@thm
\renewcommand\@thm[3]{\amsthm@thm{#1}{#2}{#3}}% so hook with arguments works
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/@thm/before}{%
  \def\temp@num{#2}%
  \ifx\@empty\temp@num
  \else
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/thmhead/before}{\MakeLinkTarget{#2}}%
  \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preliminary}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{theorem} \label{prelim}
Something here.
\end{theorem}

The jump to \cref{prelim} is wrong.

\end{document}

See hyperref-linktarget.pdf for a description of \MakeLinkTarget.
